# Is there a Salesforce method to validate Remote Objects Query Criteria and turn it into dynamic SOQL?

Tags: apex, visualforce, remote-objects

Let's say I'm [overriding the default retrieve operation for a Visualforce Remote Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_override_actions.htm) so I can use custom SOQL to execute a query and add related (nested) data. In order to create a query, it'd be ideal to re-use Salesforce's parser that they use to take the [Remote Objects Query Criteria](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_retrieve_query_object.htm) containing `where`, `offset`, and `limit`, to validate these and turn them into valid SOQL snippets I can use in my query.

Surely, this happens internally already, but is any such facility exposed to me, the developer?

For example, let's say we use JavaScript remoting / `@RemoteAction` to override `retrieve` like in this example https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/45193/7215. However, instead of calling `RemoteObjectController.retrieve`, I want to call `Database.query('SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM Orders__r) FROM Account' + criteria` to get my results using dynamic SOQL.

My goal is to define the `criteria` variable in this example. The resulting string might look like `WHERE Id = 'someSalesforceId' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2` depending on the actual criteria, but this would ideally be validated against the object to make sure the fields were valid, and that SOQL injection didn't occur. I could build that myself, but Salesforce is obviously already doing this internally, so I wonder if we can reuse that logic.

Comment: Can you add some code to demonstrate what you are doing so far?

Comment: Does the override actually let you see the criteria to begin with? I'm not sure you can do that.

Comment: I've updated the question with small examples of code. The signature for the override would be `static Map<String, Object> retrieveOverride(String type, List<String> fields, Map<String, Object> criteria)`, so you could parse the `criteria` in this example, using the syntax in the first article I linked to.

Comment: hey @jon_wu any luck? I am trying something similar here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192457/how-to-dynamically-query-in-remote-object-model

Comment: @SFDC_peter for now, I'm going with a simpler, less-performant solution. I'm going to write some code on the frontend to recursively fetch relationships, one at a time. Unfortunately, this will be one roundtrip for each traversal, but it will keep things simple for now. Later, I think we'll just add hard-coded queries with remoting, but it will be one-off for now. There's still a bit of thinking even on the backend when getting nested relationships. At least my frontend implementation will have a cache of all related IDs so it'll safe some fetches if there are multiple references to something.